# How can I convert to 512*512 image to 256*256?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I try to convert the images using following command:

```
%Image Original
imagefilename='cameraman_gray_512.tif';
I=im2double(imread(imagefilename));
%Resize the Image
J = imresize(I, 0.5);
imshow(J)
%Save the Image
imwrite(J,'cameraman_gray_256.tif','tif' )
```

I download the Lena image in 256*256 format it looks great. But I don't like J images' quality. 
Regards,

Comment: What don't you like about it? Care to share the image with us?

Comment: I try the command on Lena. >> psnr(J,K) K is the from database, J is the converted by the above command.

ans =

   30.9663

Comment: @beaker, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna

Comment: Is there any differences between J = imresize(I, [256 256]); and J = imresize(I, 0.5); @nirvana-msu

Comment: @nirvana-msu 1) The image `J` in the given code is derived from `cameraman_gray_256.tif`, not `lenna`. 2) I was actually hoping for the *resized* image and a description of what the OP considered wrong, not the source image.

Comment: @user3470711 Both use the same interpolation method and generate the same size image. You can always `edit imresize` to check.

Comment: I should have written more detailed. First, I used for camera. Then, I used for lena because I had a original 256*256 image which is downloaded from database. @beaker

Comment: And another question, Is there any differences between converting the size before converting the double or not?

Comment: Which one is better? @beaker

Comment: I check the psnr values. If double is first: 30.9768, else 30.9663. In my view, I should convert to double first before the resizing. @beaker